# Collator panicked at 'Storage root must match that calculated.'

Tags: runtime, wasm, collator, error

We have a few collators for the Kintsugi parachain actively syncing and producing blocks when they suddenly fall-over due to the following error:

```
Apr 02 21:06:00 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:00 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12082344 (0x9ef8…3509)
Apr 02 21:06:01 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:01 [Parachain]  Idle (27 peers), best: #665718 (0x7648…e130), finalized #665718 (0x7648…e130), ⬇ 15.9kiB/s ⬆ 16.8kiB/s
Apr 02 21:06:03 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:03 [Relaychain]  Idle (50 peers), best: #12082344 (0x9ef8…3509), finalized #12082341 (0xbdf5…24bb), ⬇ 312.3kiB/s ⬆ 549.4kiB/s
Apr 02 21:06:06 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:06 [Parachain]  Idle (27 peers), best: #665718 (0x7648…e130), finalized #665718 (0x7648…e130), ⬇ 7.6kiB/s ⬆ 8.3kiB/s
Apr 02 21:06:06 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:06 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12082345 (0xa6b2…9cb1)
Apr 02 21:06:06 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:06 Off-chain worker started on block 665719
Apr 02 21:06:06 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:06 [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0xa6b2df698486715d55479010149e18cd14e11196553ad920752e9e181fd69cb1 at=0x2ba467927cfdf92d41997301b1b9aa38f09cef2c365ed9676fafa71a4f5eb669
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:07 [Parachain] panicked at 'Storage root must match that calculated.', /builds/interlay/interbtc/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-f4423eebfa0046a3/22d40c7/frame/executive/src/lib.rs:488:9
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:07 [Parachain] Block prepare storage changes error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: WASM backtrace:
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     0: 0x32b297 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     1: 0x1173a - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hce09957bf3e88e08
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     2: 0xc0f4f - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::execute_block::h2b20ae17664d24fe
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     3: 0x14ff47 - <unknown>!Core_execute_block
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: 2022-04-02 21:06:07 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0x0520227ed2b74353dc2517aaf3a59e66e874fbb391a849faf6a1640812ff2f29: consensus error: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]: WASM backtrace:
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     0: 0x32b297 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     1: 0x1173a - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hce09957bf3e88e08
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     2: 0xc0f4f - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::execute_block::h2b20ae17664d24fe
Apr 02 21:06:07 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01 kintsugi[309550]:     3: 0x14ff47 - <unknown>!Core_execute_block
```

No runtime upgrades were performed and the collators all have `--execution=wasm` set. This appears to be unrecoverable until we manually restart the node.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to the broken state cache. See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9769) for more information. For now you can run your nodes with `--state-cache-size 0` to prevent this bug.